# why file hash not match after download windows kb3185330 monthly quality rollup?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, hashing

After downloading the [kb3185330 monthly quality rollup](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3185330) for Windows 7 x64 from Microsoft site, I compared the hashes for the downloaded file named : **(Windows6.1-KB3185330-x64.msu)** from the site and after being downloaded and they were totally different.

You can see the difference as below :

SHA256 (downloaded):

> B914AF618F3C8F8D2BBFB2E2945B5A379D5160D7BA98E4A3D0D8F9F078CC50F6

SHA256 (website):

> 474B24B50593ABCA810E08217205CFE076354417A0C2EBFACA3F61F86597E680

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Did you try to run the file and check if it is working or no?

Comment: @Scorpion99 It works.

Comment: @Seth Um, how about how do we know if this file is valid or not? Why is the hash that is on the website different than the file that one downloads... this makes no sense, and could indicate a very serious problem, such as a) Microsoft's update servers being compromised b) a Mitm attack c) faulty network hardware introducing random bugs into your Operating System. Even if you feel that option A and B are somehow 'paranoid', and you would be wrong, option C alone makes this unacceptable. Just because software 'works' doesn't mean that there are not serious problems with it.

Comment: Your question body doesn't contain the question itself. it just contains a statement about the hashes. That's what I'm getting at. How did you generate the hash? As MS is hosting the files you would have to ask MS for clarification. If you look at the KB page at the bottom it says: `Revision: 3.0`. Seems like that Update had problems so maybe the file was updated but the hashes weren't changed. Currently I'm getting hte same hash as you. Did you check it for a current update?

Comment: @Seth ,the title is the question,so I didn't repeat the title in question body. No, it has not been updated since this question was asked.

Comment: Yes, it was already Revision 3.0 but that doesn't mean that those Hashes don't belong to Revision 1.0 and that the update file was changed to fix some of the issues that update had. As such you would need to contact Microsoft to ask for the correct hashes. In addition for your option a/b did you check more than just that one file? The current [January](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3212646) update has the correct hash for me. As for not repeating the question in the text it's a matter of opinion I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution, with a similar problem. It was my wireless adapter, but I had to troubleshoot.

I have 3 adapters , 2 wired 1 wireless. I set fixed priorities in all adapters. Adapter-wired-A had 1, adapter-wired-B had 2 and adapter-wirelless had 3 priority. You can set it on Network sharing>Change Adapater Setting>Select the adapter>Right click>Properties>Internet Protocol Version 4>Properties>Advanced...>**Interface metric**

But I noticed the routing was still going through wireless adapter , I could validate using cmd with the command route print I had 3 default routes, but the wireds adapters had metrics around 250 to 280. It was wierd because I just set it to 1 and 2. So I think I used a VPN recently and the VPN changed my metrics.

In order to fix this mess, I download the las drivers for my wired adapters and install, then I set it the priority again and I fixed the issue. Now I have the priority 1 2 and 3 as I wanted . The bad hash was gone for every download I did, but I probed that when I download with my wireless adapter the bad hash was still there. So I changed two things in the adapter, I went to the adapter properties>Configure...>Advanced and I disabled Packet Caoalesing and throghput booster. Then I tried to download something and the bad hash was gone.

Now the priority is with the right number and I can download eveything with no hash problems.

Comment: I think you answer is unrelated to this question.